# How can I read a file and display only the relevant lines using grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to read `/var/log/messages` in order to identify a problem with the `pacemakerd`.
The problem is that the log is full with notifications from `xinetd` and `nrpe`, so the only way i know is:

```
# tail -n 2000 /var/log/messages |grep -v xinetd | grep -v nrpe |less
```

So my question is if there's a way to use the `-v xinetd and nrpe` in the same `grep`?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
grep -v "xinetd\|nrpe"
```

Comment: should be `egrep`. or `grep -E`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use `first_pattern|second_pattern` together with the `-E` option of `grep`:

```
tail -n 2000 /var/log/messages | grep -Ev "xinetd|nrpe"
```

From `man grep`:

> -E, --extended-regexp
>
> Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below). 
>   (-E is specified by POSIX.)

#### Example

```
$ cat a
hello this is me
bye this is me
and that's all

$ grep -Ev "hello|bye" a
and that's all
```

Comment: Regarding the question you just made, you can use `uniq -c` in a file to count repetitions!

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v "xinetd\|nrpe"
```

is correct and sufficient. Options like -E or egrep are not necessary.

More variaties:

```
grep -v "^xinetd\|nrpe"   # exclude lines starting with xinetd, and any nrpe"
grep -v "xinetd$\|nrpe"   # exclude lines ending with xinetd, and any nrpe"
```